# What happens when we cut a Möbius strip along a vertical line?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have the following question, when we cut a Möbius strip and separate the both parts what kind of spaces we have?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Make one and do it!

Comment: @PaulVanKoughnett Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just get a rectangle.

To see why, imagine in your sketch you cut out a tiny strip in the middle. You take the right-hand part, flip it over and then glue it to the left-hand part, in accordance with the identification arrows.

Paul Van Koughnett had the right idea in the comments $-$ make a Möbius strip and check it yourself!